# How to set minimum date for one particlar date field using Jquery/Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

I am facing one issue. I need to set `mindate` for one particular date field using Jquery and Bootstrap. I am explaining my code below.

```
<p style="position: relative">
      <input type="text" class="form-control date" value="" placeholder="Planned Date of Audit" id="planneddateofaudit" name="planneddateofaudit" readonly="" style="cursor:pointer; background-color:#fff;" />
    </p>
    <p style="position: relative">
      <input type="text" class="form-control plan date" value="" placeholder="Planned Date" id="planneddate" name="planneddate" readonly="" style="cursor:pointer; background-color:#fff;" />
    </p>


$(function()
{
    var date1  = new Date();
    var dd = date1.getDate(); 
    var mm = date1.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = date1.getFullYear();
    var compareDate1 = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);
    compareDate1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var todayDate = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy; 

    $('.plan .date').datetimepicker(
    {
        ignoreReadonly: true,
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        minDate: todayDate 
    });   
    $('.date').datetimepicker(
    {
        ignoreReadonly: true,
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    });  

    $('.datetime').datetimepicker(
    {
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm',
    });          
});
```

Here I need to set `mindate` for `Planned Date` date field and other one is will remain as it is. In my condition its not working as expected. [Here is my plunkr full code](https://plnkr.co/edit/qVEE3HznPDhfnz7vyVsN?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You must replace :

- -- $('.plan .date').datetimepicker
- ++ $('.plan.date').datetimepicker